# When PDO returns an empty object, using PDO::FETCH_OBJ, how do I echo values based upon the empty object?

Tags: php, class, pdo

In my PDO query, when no results returned, `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` retrieves no object (get_class fails with non-object, as expected).

```
$prepared_statement = $this->_adapter->prepare($sql);
$prepared_statement->bindValue(':student_id', $_student_search, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$prepared_statement->execute();
$results = $prepared_statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if (empty($results))
{
    return echo "EMPTY"; //what do I do?
}

return $results;
```

What can I do since my template is based upon the object returning values?

```
//from my code somewhere
//$student is empty
$student = $student_model->findByStudentID($studentID);

<input type="button" value="<?PHP echo $student->lastname; ?>" />
<input type="button" value="<?PHP echo $student->firstname; ?>" />
etc....
```

When the object is empty, I will receive a non-object error, which makes sense, as there is no $student object returned

What can I do when `$result` is empty? (If it matters, I am using PDO with MySQL.)

EDIT:

I ended up doing this:

```
if (empty($results))
        {
            $object = new stdClass();
            $realColumnNames = parent::getColumnNames($this->_adapter, 'students');
            foreach($realColumnNames as $column)
            {
                $object->{$column}="";
            }
            return $object;
        }
```

Here is the parent class:

```
protected function getColumnNames($adapter, $myTable)
{
    $this->myAdapter = $adapter;
    $sql = "DESCRIBE " . $myTable; //mysql only
    $prepared_statements = $this->myAdapter->prepare($sql);
    $prepared_statements->execute();
    return $results = $prepared_statements->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best way to do this but you could make an empty object ...

```
if (empty($results)){
    $results = (object) array('lastname' => '', 'firstname' => '');
}
```

Comment: I have considered it but I cannot be the only person to have experienced this.  I thought there might be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
if (empty($results))
        {
            $object = new stdClass();
            $realColumnNames = parent::getColumnNames($this->_adapter, 'students');
            foreach($realColumnNames as $column)
            {
                $object->{$column}="";
            }
            return $object;
        }
```

Here is the parent class:

```
protected function getColumnNames($adapter, $myTable)
{
    $this->myAdapter = $adapter;
    $sql = "DESCRIBE " . $myTable; //mysql only
    $prepared_statements = $this->myAdapter->prepare($sql);
    $prepared_statements->execute();
    return $results = $prepared_statements->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
}
```

Comment: this is fine, but will put additional load on your mysql server, look into caching the request if you see performance issues with heavy loads